# $2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}} \text{ } \forall \text{ } n>2$: Non-Inductive, non-calculus Proof

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the below inequality:
$$
2^n>1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}} \text{ }\{n|n\in\mathbb{N},n>2\}
$$

Here's my attempt:
Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
D &= 2^n-\left(1+n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}\right) \\
&= 2^n-\left(1+2n\sqrt{2^{n-3}}+n^22^{n-3}-n^22^{n-3}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{8}\left\{\sqrt{2^n(n^2+8)}+\sqrt{8}+n\sqrt{2^n}\right\}\left\{\sqrt{2^n(n^2+8)}-\sqrt{8}-n\sqrt{2^n}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly, $D$ being positive or negative depends on the term
$$
\sqrt{2^n(n^2+8)}-\sqrt{8}-n\sqrt{2^n}
$$

since the other term is positive for $n>0$

Let
$$
d = \sqrt{2^n(n^2+8)}-\left(\sqrt{8}+n\sqrt{2^n}\right)
$$

Now,
$$
n>2
$$

First:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\implies & n^2+8 > 12 \\
\implies & 2^n>2^2 \\
\therefore \text{ } & \sqrt{2^n(n^2+8)} > 4\sqrt{3} \approx 6.928
\end{aligned}
$$

Second:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{8}+n\sqrt{2^n} > \sqrt{8}+4 \approx 6.828
\end{aligned}
$$

**I'm not sure if I can subtract the second from the first and hence declare $d$ to be positive and consequently $D$ as positive.**

Help please! Kindly don't suggest inductive and calculus proofs. Just basic algebra.

Comment: No, you can't. For example, $3>2$ and $4>1$ but $3-4<0$.

Comment: Jujustum exactly. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: @AbhishekAUdupa You can't subtract inequalities. But you should be able to show that $(2^n-1)^2 \gt n^2 2^{n-1}$ without induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What you seek is not really possible…**

$2^n$ has two possible definitions:

1. If $n$ is allowed to be any real, then $$2^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{((0.69315\dots)n)^k}{k!}}$$
2. If $n$ is a positive integer, then $$2^n=\begin{cases}1&n=0\\2\cdot2^{n-1}&n>0\end{cases}$$

(There are a few other definitions, but they are all variants on these in some sense.)

If we must prove a property of $2^n$, then either we use definition #1, which uses calculus *in the very definition*; or we use definition #2, which uses induction similarly.

Thus whether a solution using "basic algebra" is even *possible* depends quite strongly on what "basic algebra" tells us about $2^n$.

**…but one can come close:**

Some identities involving exponentials admit a change of variables that removes the exponential.  For example $$2^{2n}-2^{n+1}+1\geq0$$ is the quadratic $$x^2-2x+1\geq0$$ with $x=2^n$.  In those circumstances, we can avoid relying on definitions of $2^n$; but your inequality is not of this form.

I do not know of any proposition that (a) does not admit such a change of variables and (b) avoids using the definition of exponential in some way.  But we can *hide* such use of the definition behind a relatively simple, inoffensive lemma (that will then require calculus/induction to prove).

**A solution sketch:**

One such lemma is the following: $$2^n-1\geq n^2\text{ for }n\geq3\tag{1}$$  To see this, take the "[discrete derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)": compare how each side changes as we shift $n\mapsto n+1$.  (You'll need to do this twice.)  Concluding that the claim holds for all $n$ once we understand this shift requires induction in a formal proof; but (1) is a reasonable proposition to assume on its own.

If so, then we can follow dxiv's suggestion in the comments (give him an upvote!).  First suppose $$(2^n-1)^2>n^2 2^{n-1}\tag{2}$$  Then, taking positive square roots, we have $$2^n-1>n\sqrt{2^{n-1}}$$ and can rearrange.  So, why does (2) hold?

Well, since $n>2$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $n\geq3$.  Thus $$2^n-1\geq n^2\tag{1 again}$$  Also, $$2^n-1=2^{n-1}+(2^{n-1}-1)\geq2^{n-1}\tag{3}$$  (Note that (3) *can* be proven using "basic algebra"…but it admits the change of variables $x=2^{n-1}$.)  Since both (1) and (3) hold *and have nonnegative terms*, their product, viz. (2), holds as well.